# In React router dom can i pass a props in a Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

in React router dom can i pass a props in a Link?

Is there a way that i can pass props into Link then just the component?

I'm trying to pass props inside a Link like this.

```
function App(){
    const test = "Hello"
    return(
        <Link to="/detail" test={test}> detail </Link>
    )
}
```

In my detail component i can call like this.

```
function detail(){
return(
    <p>{test}</p>
    )   
}
```

I'm sorry if this example is very hard to understand, I don't know how to give proper example.

Comment: yes using `state` prop -> as `<Link to= {{ pathname : "/detail",  state: { urdata : "dummy"} }}> detail </Link>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `state` prop you can as below

**Using React Router - V5**

[Docs ref for Link - V5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

```
function App(){
    const test = "Hello"
    return(
        <Link to= {{ pathname : "/detail",  state: { test: "dummy"} }}> detail </Link>
    )
}
```

**Using React Router - V6**

[Docs ref for Link - V6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#link)

```
function App(){
    const test = "Hello"
    return(
        <Link to= "/detail"  state= {{ test: "dummy" }} > detail </Link>
    )
}
```

and get the value using `useLocation` hook which is same in *V5 & V6*

In my detail component I can call like this.

```
function detail(){
const {state} = useLocation();
return(
    <p>{state.test}</p>
    )   
}
```

Comment: Since it's not clear at all which version of `react-router-dom` OP is using, just be aware that the [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) component API changed in v6, `state` is a prop on the link instead of a property on the `to` object.

Comment: Sure @Drew, updated the answer with both versions , thanks for the hint 